# Can't find /opt/ directory on mac os 10.7.5

Tags: php, macos, apache

I am struggling with setting up a correct php version on my mac, and have found out that I don't have an /opt/ directory.

```
-bash: cd: /opt/: No such file or directory
```

or

```
-bash: cd: /opt/local/etc: No such file or directory
```

Is it possible? How can I deal with this issue. My apache reveals an incorrect php version, and to make it use the correct one, I have to add `LoadModule php5_module /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_php54.so` to httpd.conf, but I can't do that since I don't have an /opt directory. 
I will be truly grateful for your help - please, be specific, because I am a newbie and all this is very difficult for me. 
Thank you very much!

Comment: Perhaps you're starting in the wrong folder. Try `cd ~/.` and `pwd` and see where you are.

Comment: Why do you think you should have `/opt`? I only have `X11` in my `/opt` and I installed `X11` myself so it is perfectly likely that there is no `/opt` by default. I suspect your PHP module is located elsewhere - how did you install PHP?

Comment: @MarkSetchell, using MacPorts I reckon.

Comment: "LoadModule php5_module /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_php54.so" — Have you installed that version of PHP there yet?

Comment: PHP 5.4 is [so old that PHP no longer support it](http://php.net/supported-versions.php), not even for security fixes, it is unlikely to be "a correct php version".

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am just learning CS, so I take lots of things for granted if I find some information on professional sites. I assumed that /opt is a default directory. To install the new 5.5.37 php version I used this command `curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.5 `; `cd ; nano .bach_profile` ; `export PATH="/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH"`; `source ~/.bash_profile` ; `/usr/local/php5/bin/php --version` showed  PHP 5.5.37 (cli) ; I will add more in the next comment - not enough space

Comment: next: 'sudo mv /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php5328'; 'sudo ln -s /usr/local/php5/bin/php /usr/bin/php'; 'which php'; '/usr/bin/php'; both '/usr/bin/php --version' and 'php -v' showed the required php version: PHP 5.5.37 (cli) (built: Jun 26 2016 13:53:04)

Comment: Any reason for using such an old version of OSX? It is free to upgrade. Also, it is way simpler to install packages on OSX with `homebrew`... http://brew.sh

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes, I have to use the old osx for now - the main reason is the absence of enough knowledge and hence the fear of worsening things even more. I will upgrade (actually, as I know I can't upgrade to 10.8 for free) once I have much better understand of cs - it's my only computer, and I can't ruin things. As to additional applications, I try not to use those because setting up AMP on my osx should not have caused so much trouble as it actually did )